# ITMS-90086 Missing 64-bit support

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store

We have a `Xamarin` application that we are trying to deploy to the apple appstore, but when we try to submit the application for review we get the exception `ITMS-90086 Missing 64-bit support`. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here are the build options for my Xamarin project showing that `ARMv7 + ARM64` is selected for the `Supported architectures` setting.

[image]

Note from the screenshot that the configuration is set to `Release`; I did read in one of the Xamarin appstore guidelines that this must be set to `Appstore`, but I do not have that configuration in my project. (See screenshot below). Could this have anything to do with the error we are getting?

[image]

We are able to set the `Active configuration` to `Appstore\Device` in the `Project` menu and have done so. So `Appstore` configuration is just not available in the project build options.

[image]

We also make use of 4 statically linked libraries which we recompiled in Xcode after updating to `iOS SDK 8.3`. Here is a sample screenshot of the build settings for one of our statically linked libraries.

[image]

Here is a summary of the actions that we performed to try get our application submitted:

- Upgraded `Xcode` to the latest version with `iOS 8.3 SDK` installed
- Upgraded to the latest version of `Xamarin Studio`
- Upgraded to latest version of `Xamarin.iOS` (Version: 8.8.2.4)
- Migrated the application to the `Unified API`
- Recompiled our static libraries in Xcode using `iOS 8.3 SDK`
- Used `btouch-native` to import the libraries into our `Xamarin` project.
- Changed the `Active configuration` to 'Appstore\Device`.
- Configured the correct provisioning profile in the `iOS bundle signing` section
- Selected `ARMv7 + ARM64` for the `Supported architectures` build setting.

We can compile that application with `ARM64` architecture specified in the build settings; we can create the archive; we can even validate the archive in `Xcode` and it *passes* the validation. But when we do the submission we get this error.

Does anyone know why this error occurs and what we could do to try resolve it?

Comment: Probably you are using another library inside the project that does not support 64bit

Comment: The problem is that for some reason the AppStore configuration doesn't show up when editing the iOS Build options. Can you post your .csproj file somewhere?

Comment: @Andrea I have checked my libraries a number of times to ensure that arm64 is included in the valid configurations, but I will check them again.

Comment: @Rolf Bjarne Kvinge I have uploaded the project file here: http://www.filedropper.com/mobileforms

Comment: Is there some way to test the archive for 64-bit support without submitting it? The reason I ask is because the application has lots of dependencies and any one of them could be causing this issue. Besides the application project there is also a library project in the same solution and 4 other statically linked libraries that are compiled with Xcode. Ideally I would want to try find out which library is causing the problem, but I cannot remove a library and submit because then I would be submitting an incomplete app. Any ideas how to narrow down where the problem lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your project file doesn't have an `AppStore` configuration.

To solve:

- Right-click your project => Options.
- Select Build/Configurations.
- Select Distribution/iPhone, and Copy to:

  - Name: AppStore
  - Platform: iPhone
- OK

Now you should be able to select the AppStore configuration and set the architecture properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added the AppStore configuration to my project but unfortunately it did not help. I still get the error when submitting the application.

Comment: Are you able to select the AppStore configuration when editing the iOS Build options now? If so, can you add `-v -v -v -v` to the additional mtouch arguments, rebuild, and post the complete build log?

Comment: Yes, I am able to select AppStore configuration in the build options. Here is the build log: http://www.filedropper.com/mobileformsbuildlog

Comment: That's not a rebuild, that's just a build (lots of "outputs are up-to-date" in that log). Can Clean & Build and get that build log?

Comment: Sorry. Here you go, here is the build log after a clean: http://www.filedropper.com/mobileformsbuildlog_1

Comment: That build produced an app with both 32bit and 64bit architectures (armv7+arm64), so it should be fine. You can confirm this by using the following command: `file /Users/brucehill/Projects/mobileforms_apple/Mobileforms/bin/iPhone/Release/Mobileforms.app /Mobileforms` from a terminal window.

Comment: I think you're posting the wrong binary, look at the path to the ipa: `Tool /usr/bin/zip execution started with arguments: -r -y /Users/brucehill/Projects/mobileforms_apple/Mobileforms/bin/iPhone/Release/MobileForms.ipa Payload iTunesArtwork@2x ` (it ends up in the Release subdirectory, instead of AppStore subdirectory).

Comment: Thanks, Rolf. Yes you were right. I changed the output folder to 'AppStore', cleaned my bin folder completely and also deleted all of the archives. Now when I rebuild, archive and submit I no longer get that error message reported. Thanks for your help.